# laravel 4.2 file upload issue

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

**Laravel 4.2**

My Code -

image-upload.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Files here</h1>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{ @url('image-handle') }}">
   <input type="file" name="image" id="avatarImage" />
   <input type='hidden' name='_token' value='{{ @csrf_token() }}' />
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Routes -

```
Route::get('image-upload', function()
{
    return View::make('image-upload');
});

Route::get('image-handle', function()
{
    return Input:: file( 'image' ) -> getFileName();
});
```

All i want to do is **var_dump** the file after submit but unfortunately i get is **"Whoops, looks like something went wrong".**

Check The image of the error:
[image: Error]

How to solve this problem and upload image successfully in laravel 4.2 ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a get verb on your image-handle route and your form is type=post
Make them match.

```
Route::post('image-handle', function()
{
    return Input:: file( 'image' ) -> getFileName();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change your routes to POST request you are using form POST method and you can change your code.

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' =>  route('upload') 'image-handle', 'files' => true)) }}

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('image', 'Upload File') }}
        {{ Form::file('image') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
    </p>
{{ Form::close() }}




 Route::post('image-handle',[
            'as' => 'upload',
            'uses'=>'UploadController@uploadFile'
        ]);


//UploadController


public function uploadFile()
{

     if (Input::hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }  


}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is frowned upon.

Comment: can you explain whats the issue?

Comment: the request mentioned in routes are get and form has a post method so in routes it should be post verb